# Loop through divs to add a class in a random order

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have multiple elements with the same **'pic'** class, each has its own incrementing class (pos_1, pos2, pos_3, etc) which controls its position on the page.

I want to create a loop so that each element has the **'animate'** class added to it, but i want to loop through the elements in a random order.

How would i do this if i didn't want to use a hard-coded array of the elements in the JS.

An example of my html element is:

```
<div class="pic pos_1">
    ...
</div>

<div class="pic pos_2">
    ...
</div>

<div class="pic pos_3">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Use Math.random() which returns a number between 0 and 1. Depending on the number of elements, divide the range of 0-1.
Therefore you can use it like this.
Suppose an elements will have class 'animate' if and only if Math.random() returned value is >0.7.
Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var arr = $('.pic').get();
while(arr.length){
    var el = arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
    $(el).addClass('animate')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PvegC/)

Update

```
var arr = $('.pic').get();

function random(arr) {
    if (!arr.length) {
        return;
    }
    var el = arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length), 1);
    $(el).addClass('animate');
    setTimeout(function () {
        random(arr);
    }, 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
}
random(arr);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vXDes/)

Comment: Good answer. Is it possible to add the animate class to the elements at random intervals between 1 - 2 seconds?

Comment: Great job. Last part, is it possible that multiple .pic elements move at the same time rather than just one at a time?

Comment: If they're moving at the same time why would you bother applying the .animate class in a random order? I'm confused.

Comment: Because I am applying a CSS3 animation class. I just want to CSS animation to happen at different time intervals so the pics look like they are coming down different times

Comment: Much appreciate your help @ArunPJohny. I have something working now!

Answer (score 0):

create a array with length of number of divs you have and shuffle that array. Now loop through that array using its index and assign class accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Get the total count of pictures in your page and randomly select an index of picture which you want to show

```
//Remove 'animate' class from all pictures.
$('.pic').removeClass('animate');
//Count of pictures in your page.
var picCount = $('.pic').length();      
//Random index of picture.
var picIndexToShow = Math.floor(Math.random() * picCount);

//Random picture from page
var randomPic = $($('.pic')[picIndexToShow]);
//Add 'animate' class
randomPic.addClass('animate');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was my fault, i didn't make myself clear. It is then to add the animate class to .pic elements in different time intervals so they appear on the page in a random order?